# Using load-grunt-config with Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

#### Context

I have a few grunt tasks that I've already written, and I'd like to use them with a new project I'm writing in Sails.js.

With Sails.js, you can add additional grunt tasks by adding a JS file to the `/tasks/register` folder. Before we get to the file I've added, let's talk about the problem.

#### The Problem

Sails won't lift. Debugger shows:

```
debug: --------------------------------------------------------
error: ** Grunt :: An error occurred. **
error: 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "clean.dev" missing.
```

The issue in question is obviously with grunt, so then I try `grunt build` (which automatically runs with `sails lift`):

```
Running "clean:dev" (clean) task
Verifying property clean.dev exists in config...ERROR
>> Unable to process task.
Warning: Required config property "clean.dev" missing. Use --force to continue.
```

From this, I've garnered that this is a path issue. Let's take a look at the file I've added.

#### /tasks/register/customTask.js

The task here loads [load-grunt-config](https://github.com/firstandthird/load-grunt-config), which is the source of my problems:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // measures the time each task takes
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);
    
    // This require statement below causes my issue
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        config: '../../package.json',
        scope: 'devDependencies',
        overridePath: require('path').join(process.cwd(), '/asset-library/grunt')
    });
    
    grunt.registerTask('customTask', [
        'newer:jshint',
        'newer:qunit',
        'newer:concat',
        'newer:cssmin',
        'newer:uglify'
    ]);

};
```

I had assumed that using `overridePath` instead of `configPath` would solve my issue, but alas, it's not quite that simple. Is there some way to make it so that I can use my own custom tasks folder with `load-grunt-config` like I've done in other projects, or is there some magic conditional I can wrap the `require` statement around?

I only need it to run with `grunt customTask`, and *not* run with `grunt *` (anything else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this was actually pretty easy. All I had to do was change the `grunt.registerTask` call in my customTask.js file from this:

```
grunt.registerTask('customTask', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:qunit',
    'newer:concat',
    'newer:cssmin',
    'newer:uglify'
]);
```

to this:

```
grunt.registerTask('customTask', 'My custom tasks', function() {
    // The require statement is only run with "grunt customTask" now!
    require('load-grunt-config')(grunt, {
        config: '../../package.json',
        scope: 'devDependencies',
        overridePath: require('path').join(process.cwd(), '/asset-library/grunt')
    });
    grunt.task.run([
        'newer:jshint',
        'newer:qunit',
        'newer:concat',
        'newer:cssmin',
        'newer:uglify'
    ]);
});
```

In case it's not clear, I *did* have to move the `require('load-grunt-config')` call, so if you're copy + pasting, make sure to remove the require statement that's outside the `grunt.registerTask` call.

[You can find more information about custom Grunt tasks here](http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks).